# How to create package from existing project with Swift Package Manager?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager, modularization

Is it possible to create package from existing project ( UIKit application ) in Xcode13 ?

I have implemented application but it too big and take too much time on building phase. Because of that, I want to separate to stand-alone modular app ( mini app ) by pack them to package with Swift package manager.

Is it possible to do that ? Or has better way to implement modularization application.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think SPM is the way to go currently, cause you can easily handle versioning for the package.

You can create a new package locally in a different directory which you'll later add as a new repository.

Then move all the contents you want into that package. Don't forget to set the **access to public** so it will be accessible from the consumer applications. Also go to your project settings and in the tab *Package Dependencies*, click the plus button to add a new package, click on the add local and choose your newly created package. Also go to the target settings and add the package in *Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content* section.

For your Package file you would get something like this where you'll need to setup the platforms you'll use it with, my example package is named SPM1.

```
// swift-tools-version: 5.6
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "SPM1",

    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v13) // set your minimal version here
    ],

    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "SPM1",
            targets: ["SPM1"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "SPM1",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "SPM1Tests",
            dependencies: ["SPM1"]),
    ]
)
```

In your application, do the import like so:

```
import SPM1
```

And start using your new package.

Once everything is OK, you can add your package in a new git repository. Don't forget to version your package in the format X.Y.Z (like 1.0.0) by tagging your commits. Go back to the project settings and add the URL + the branch or version (tag).

You can use both locally and remotely. The advantage of having it locally is the agility to build and run quickly when developing.

I hope that helps! :)