# Can I create mini app with Swift package manager?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, modularization

After I code iOS application for awhile, I faced problem with project's size and build time. I found some concept about super app / mini app.

According a question, I implement my application and I want to separate to a miniapp ( separate project ) but I don't know to how to connect it together and how to build them stand-alone.

After I made some research about concept, I think I can made my miniapp to a library by SPM.

Is it possible to move every thing from existing project to package with SPM ( storyboard, extension, localize, depedencies, info.plist, permission ) ?

[image: Concept Super App - Mini App example]

Answer (score 0):

you can do that, here's my answer to someone who wanted to do the same https://stackoverflow.com/a/72476153/6808357. I also advise you to read this Apple documentation on how to handle your ressources/assets https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/bundling_resources_with_a_swift_package.

I hope it helps! :)